# How can I make a series of <p> elements display horizontally?

Tags: css

I thought I could just use `float: left`, but this did not work.  I tried setting the containing div to both `width:auto` and `width:100%` but this seemingly had no effect as well.

```
// ... snip

#mi_control{
  position:  absolute;
  top:  220px;
  left: -20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu_bottom{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 18px;
  float: left;
}
.menu_bottom:hover{
  cursor: pointer
}

</style>

<div id='mi_holder' class='proof_of_existance'>
    <div id='mi_box'>

    // .. snip

    <div id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
      <p id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Foo &copy; </p>
      <p id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About</p>
      <p id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</p>
      <p id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</p>
      <p id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you use float: left, you should put widths to the elements

Comment: The `<p>` element is by default a block level element, and therefore will take up 100% of the containing parent's width. Should you want to arrange them horizontally, you either have to force a flex box layout (and disable `flex-wrap`, but that should be disabled by default if the browser supports the flexbox specifications), or float the elements *and* declaring a reduced width (a fraction of the parent's width, for example).

Comment: Horizontal like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0wg79xea/

Comment: Working fine [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/5uew6kcb/).

Comment: @cadegalt Based on your requirements, I believe flexbox would be the most relevant solution to you. `display: inline-block` would work (again, with declared width), but you will have to use dirty hacks to remove whitespace between `<p>` elements.

Comment: @cadegalt- The code that you gave us works fine already. It's probably being caused by another style that's not in your example code.

Comment: @cadegalt - Try reproducing the problem in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p style="display:inline-block">Some text!</p>
<p style="display:inline-block">More text!</p>
```

That being said, the paragraph tag is antiquated for interface use. It directly implies certain spacing that you would have to override in the CSS. You should reserve the paragraph tag for actual inline paragraphs of text. Use div or span tags for interface layout. For example:

```
.menuitem { display: inline-block; min-width: 72px; background-color: #AAAAFF; }

<div class="menuitem">Some text!</div>
<div class="menuitem">More text!</div>
```

Here's a fiddle of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/nqey10p0/

The primary reason to use inline-block is to have the content behave like a line of text, but be able to force width and height like in an image.

Comment: Yeah, `p` is definitely not antiquated.

Comment: I should have been more specific. For the use in the original question, it's definitely antiquated. Anything having to do with layout elements should be a div or span and styled with classes. The paragraph tag is only correct if it is truly a paragraph of text. In that case it provides semantic meaning.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify the reasoning behind not using the paragraph tag. I've also added a fiddle of the code in action.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `display: inline-block` on the `p` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/q5ar9jLb/1/

Comment: @cadegalt - it looks like using `float: left` was working all along. I think that `display: inline-block` is a bit more straightforward, though; it is obvious that you are displaying those elements inline (horizontally) instead of blocked (vertically).

Answer (score 1):

A rehash of my comment: the `<p>` element is, by default, a **block level element**, and therefore will take up 100% of the containing parent's width. Should you want to arrange them horizontally, you either have to force a flexbox layout (and disable `flex-wrap`, but that should be disabled by default if the browser supports the flexbox specifications), or float the elements and declaring a reduced width (a fraction of the parent's width, for example).

Here is an example of your code using the recommended flexbox layout. To alter the arrangement of items (how individual elements should be arranged), you can tweak the `justify-content` value. I have removed extraenous styles to the `#mi_control` element, just for the sake of a more simplified example—the use of positioning should not affect how flexbox will be interpreted though.

```css
#mi_control {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu_bottom {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.menu_bottom:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div id='mi_holder' class='proof_of_existance'>
  <div id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
    <p id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Arcmarks &copy;</p>
    <p id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About</p>
    <p id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</p>
    <p id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</p>
    <p id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some addition tips:

- You might want to look at using (un)ordered list, since your content appears to be something that semantically belongs to a list.
- Read up more about [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)